# Finding minimum value in a dictionary - TypeError int object not callable

Tags: python

My ML class involves me to find the leaves in a decision tree for which the error value is the least. The leaves and error values are stored in a dictionary (below output)

{5: 35044.51299744237, 25: 29016.41319191076, 50: 27405.930473214907, 100: 27282.50803885739, 250: 27893.822225701646, 500: 29454.18598068598}

Now, the optimal solution in this dictionary should be 100, as it has the least error rate.

The code snippet is as follows:

```
candidate_max_leaf_nodes = [5, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500]

for i in candidate_max_leaf_nodes:
#stores key,value pair of leaf_nodes, and their error values
    mydict[i] = get_mae(i,train_X,val_X,train_y,val_y)
print(mydict)


#  Find the best value of max_leaf_nodes (it will be either 5, 25, 50, 100, 250 or 500)
```

The code that Im trying for the minimum value is as below:

```
tmp = min(mydict.values()) 
best_tree_size = [key for key in mydict if mydict[key] == tmp]
```

However, I Keep getting **TypeError**: 'int' object is not callable.  Could someone explain where I'm going wrong? And can I find the min value in a more optimal way?

Comment: The shown code works for me.

Comment: This is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have defined an integer variable with the name `min`. Don't do that (or `del min` before you call the `min()` function).

Comment: Great Spot! The website had the older version of Notebook, hadn't refreshed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
my_dict = {'x':500, 'y':5874, 'z': 560}

key_min = min(my_dict.keys(), key=(lambda k: my_dict[k]))
```

Comment: it works for me. `key_min` will give the key of min value

Comment: Yup, it works! could you explain the key = ... part, thats the confusing part for me

Comment: @adv510 - From the [`min()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min): "The _key_ argument specifies
a one-argument ordering function …" - The function ist just returning the values of which the minimum is to be found; without that, the minimum of `my_dict.keys()`, i. e. `5`, would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Since this says TypeError, this could be because the value returned for my_dict could be "Int" instead of "Dict". There seems no error with your code. Check if the dictionary is correct. Your code works for me.

`mydict = {'a':50, 'b':500, 'c': 50, 'd':5000, 'e':50000, 'f': 50}`

`tmp = min(mydict.values())`

`best_tree_size = [key for key in mydict if mydict[key] == tmp]`

`print(best_tree_size)`

['a', 'c', 'f']